# Change the language everywhere

Tags: samsung, settings, languages

I changed the language of my phone (Samsung J7 2017) from Polish to French. So far so good, but there are many remnants of the language the phone was shipped in. For instance, the footer of new email, youtube suggestions, the news feed and so on are still in Polish.

Is there a way how to change the language of all system settings ? Or do I have to find those settings one by one?

Comment: Some apps are just not properly translated (i.e. does not contain translation for all strings in the app), especially when talking about less popular languages. For now my advice is to just flash a factory firmware designated for France.